# Swap number digit order by separate a number into arrays and then merge

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I can't elaborate a program with arrays language C.

The console received 4 numbers. I want to change the first number digits and multiply with the other.

**Example input**: `1260`

**Desire output**: Change 12 to 21 and them multiple by 60 -> so output will be `1260` (as `21 * 60`)

This is my current code:

```
int main() {
    int number, temp;
    int newnumber[4];
    int n = 3;

    printf("put the number");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    do {
        newnumber[n] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        n--;
    } while (n >= o);

    temp = newnumber[1];
    newnumber[1] = newnumber[2];
    newnumber[2] = temp;
}
```

know how i do 21 multiply with 60?

Comment: `while (n >= o);` You are using `o` instead of `0`.

Comment: u are right, it's 0. I write badly here,

Comment: Carlos, it is bad practice to change your question with what you learn from the comments and answers because now the comments and answer don't make sense anymore.

Comment: Are you always get 2 numbers with 2 digit each?

Comment: Paul i only change o to 0 because i wrote wrong. David, i received 1 number with 4 digits, i want change 1 digite with 2 digit. and the number formed by second and first digits multiply with number formed with third and fourth digit.

Comment: @kiranBiradar, probably he transcribed the code and made a typo.  In case he wrote `o` actuallly, the code should not compile.

Comment: @CarlosMota, as a reminder and in respect to the `o` typo, please, read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on how to submit code to StackOverflow.  It's very important you submit full example code that shows your error to find for it, as normally people, unaware of the mistake they did, don't transcribe it to the submitted code.  And the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at your example:
1260 => change 2 with 1, and multiply 21 with 60.

The permutation in your main function is wrong, cause you changed numbers at the index 1 (second position) and 2 (third position).

Back to your question, you can get the result you're looking for by doing the oppisite of what you did to get the units, tens and hundreds...

```
int main() {
    int number, temp1, temp2;
    int newnumber[4];
    int n = 3;

    printf("put the number");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    do {
        newnumber[n] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        n--;
    } while (n >= 0);

    temp1 = newnumber[0];
    newnumber[0] = newnumber[1];
    newnumber[1] = temp1;

    temp1 = newnumber[0] * 10;
    temp1 += newnumber[1];

    temp2 = newnumber[2] * 10;
    temp2 += newnumber[3];

    printf("%d", temp1 * temp2);
}
```

Comment: `21 * 60 != 660` You should fix Your Code.

Comment: Indeed, i got the value at the first index before doing the permutation. It's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I would have go with slightly different approach: first separate the numbers. Then call function to change the number order.

If you always get numbers with 2 digit you can do this:

```
int first  = number / 100;
int second = number % 100;
```

And a function to swap the digit:

```
function swapDigits(int num) {
    int ans = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        ans = ans * 10 + num % 10;
        num /= 10; 
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Now just do `second * swapDigits(first)` to get your result.

I'm not `c` expert so verify my code before use...

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions always hold you can keep it simple and do something like this:

```
int main() {
    int number;
    int newnumber[4];
    int n = 3;

    printf("put the number");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    do {
        newnumber[n] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        n--;
    } while (n >= 0);

    printf("And the result: %d\n", (newnumber[1] * 10 + newnumber[0]) * (newnumber[2] * 10 + newnumber[3]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you are not getting the individual digits, but pairs and the like.  Just get the last two digits in one shot:

```
int rem = number % 100;  /* last two digits */
number /= 100;
int msd = number % 10;   /* next, third digit */
number /= 10;
int lsd = number % 10;   /* most significant digit */
/* I don't assume you have more digits, because you are doing different
 * operations with them, no pattern up to here, but you should continue
 * your approach here. */
int out = (msd * 10 + lsd) * rem;
```

should give you a solution.  No arrays needed.